# How can I filter grouped bar chart by dataset index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I started using ChartJS recently and stumbled into a problem applying filters to a grouped bar chart.

I'm measuring the time some pages in my website take to respond and within each page there are some actions (like clicking on a button) that have individual response times. With the result I'm creating a chart which groups each response time by action.

After drawing the chart, I can use the default legend to filter each series but I'd like to be able to apply a filter by action.

From my research, most problems are related to series filtering instead of show/hiding a specific index of each dataset. A possible solution would be to redraw the whole chart with only the necessary data but since it comes from an AJAX call, it'd be better to avoid calling it every time someone changes the filter dropdown.

I've added a dropdown list with each action label and in the "OnChange" method of the dropdown it should only show the selected action for every series.

Example code: [Here](https://codepen.io/graz21/pen/PvOKpd)

The OnChange function of the dropdown is as follow:

```
function FilterByEvent(dropdown){
  var chartName = dropdown.id.replace('_filter', 'Chart');
  var chart = null;
  var selectedIndex = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;

  Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (instance) {
    if (instance.chart.canvas.id == chartName)
      chart = instance.chart;
  })

  if (chart != null){
    $.each(chart.config.data.datasets, function (index, value) {
      value.data = [value.data[selectedIndex]];
    });  
    chart.config.data.labels = [chart.config.data.labels[selectedIndex]];
    chart.update();
  }
}
```

With the current function I'm able to select only the datasets that I want, but I lose all the other information.

[image: Current]

If I change to another action, the result is an empty chart because, obviously, the data was erased in the first filter.

The expected result is to be able to filter dataset indexes according to the selected action in the filter by, without losing the datasets.

[image: Example]

Is there anyway to do this using ChartJS or should I keep the data, for instance, in a local var and repopulate the datasets in each filter?